# Highlighting top row in react-native ListView

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently trying to highlight the top element in a react native ListView.

Is it possible to for ListView identify which row component is located at the top of the view on scroll?

If not, how would I go about selecting the lowest integer rowID of the visible rows?

```
renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    return (
      <MyRow
        {...rowData}
        key={rowData.detailID}
        onDetailPress={() => this.onDetailPress(rowData, rowID)}
      />
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onChangeVisibleRows` which gives you a list of the visible rows and the rows that have changed their visibility. Something like this should do:

```
<MyRow
    {...rowData}
    key={rowData.detailID}
    onDetailPress={() => this.onDetailPress(rowData, rowID)}
    onChangeVisibleRows={(visible, changed) => this.highlightRow(visible[0])}
/>
```

You would probably need to update the data source with the item you want to be highlighted containing a state that will indicate it.